Line: 5, Column: 24 static can only be used on methods of a top level type
I have a Apex Test Class and in the debug I'm getting the following error: Line: "5, Column: 24
static can only be used on methods of a top level type".
That's my code:
@isTest
public class InternalExecSponsorHandlerTest {

    @isTest
    public static void testAddOpportunityTeamMembers() {
        // Setup test data
        // Create test Users
        User ceo = new User(
            Email = 'ceo@test.com',
            Username = 'ceo@test.com',
            ProfileId = UserInfo.getProfileId(),
            UserRoleId = '00E3g000000UL8J', // Chief Executive Officer
            LastName = 'CEO',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Sao_Paulo',
            LocaleSidKey = 'pt_BR',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'pt_BR'
        );
        
        User cro = new User(
            Email = 'cro@test.com',
            Username = 'cro@test.com',
            ProfileId = UserInfo.getProfileId(),
            UserRoleId = '00E3g000000Sg4D', // Chief Revenue Officer
            LastName = 'CRO',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Sao_Paulo',
            LocaleSidKey = 'pt_BR',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'pt_BR'
        );
        
        User headCSG = new User(
            Email = 'headcsg@test.com',
            Username = 'headcsg@test.com',
            ProfileId = UserInfo.getProfileId(),
            UserRoleId = '00ENs000002QLnd', // Head CSG
            LastName = 'Head CSG',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Sao_Paulo',
            LocaleSidKey = 'pt_BR',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'pt_BR'
        );

        // Create test Account with a Customer Success Manager
        Account acc = new Account(
            Name = 'Test Account',
            BillingCountry = 'Brazil',
            Industry = 'Consumer Goods',
            CS_Leader__c = headCSG.Id
        );
        
        insert new List<User>{ceo, cro, headCSG};
        insert acc;
        
        // Create test Opportunity
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
            Name = 'Test Opportunity',
            StageName = 'R2 - Renewal Pre-Alignment',
            CloseDate = Date.today() + 30,
            AccountId = acc.Id,
            Internal_Exec_Sponsors_Renewal__c = 'CEO;CRO;Head of Customer Success',
            RecordTypeId = '0123g0000001t3dAAA' // Replace with actual RecordTypeId
        );
        
        insert opp;
        
        Test.startTest();
        
        // Execute the handler method
        InternalExecSponsorHandler handler = new InternalExecSponsorHandler();
        handler.addOpportunityTeamMembers(new Set<Id>{opp.Id});
        
        Test.stopTest();
        
        // Verify the OpportunityTeamMembers were added correctly
        List<OpportunityTeamMember> teamMembers = [SELECT OpportunityId, UserId, TeamMemberRole FROM OpportunityTeamMember WHERE OpportunityId = :opp.Id];
        
        // Assertions
        System.assertEquals(3, teamMembers.size(), 'There should be 3 team members added to the opportunity');
        
        // Map of expected roles and user IDs
        Map<String, Id> roleToUserId = new Map<String, Id>{
            'CEO' => ceo.Id,
            'CRO' => cro.Id,
            'Head of Customer Success' => headCSG.Id
        };

        for (OpportunityTeamMember tm : teamMembers) {
            System.assert(roleToUserId.containsKey(tm.TeamMemberRole), 'Unexpected TeamMemberRole: ' + tm.TeamMemberRole);
            System.assertEquals(roleToUserId.get(tm.TeamMemberRole), tm.UserId, 'The UserId for role ' + tm.TeamMemberRole + ' should match');
        }
    }
}

That would be in the line public void testAddOpportunityTeamMembers() {
Please, help meeee :( I'm not a developer so I'm getting it from GPT lol unfortunately it seems that GPT don't know how to fix this.
I don't have errors in the debug or tests of the apex class and the trigger class, only in the test class. Everything is running according to the expected in Sandbox.
I just wanna deploy it!

Are you pasting this code in the dev console's anonymous apex window and getting the error there? BTW, the class should ideally be marked @IsTest as well.

Hi @PhilW, yep! I'm pasting it in the console's anonymous apex window. I run the that and got this error: "System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): Account, original object: User: []". Ps.: the isTest is in the code, I cut it when I copy it.

You can't copy-paste a unit test class into the Execute Anonymous window. That produces an error because Execute Anonymous basically builds an anonymous class around the code you put into the window, and inner classes can't have static properties or methods.
You'd get the same error if you wrote this in Execute Anonymous:
public class X {
  static Integer y;
}

You need to create a new class using the File menu, provide the name you want to use, then copy-paste your code into the class, and save. Your code also has some additional problems that may prevent deployment. The main one is that you are using hard-coded ID values, which won't necessarily be portable across organizations. Consider using queries instead.

Hi! I already did it, all my codes are saved, this same error happens when I go into 'Test' > 'New Run'. But thanks for the information, that's good to know!

A Warning
ChatGPT and other similar LLM "AI" tools are not a replacement for a developer. It's not suitable for bridging large gaps in knowledge. LLMs are statistical models, not actual knowledge, and they frequently make mistakes (sometimes small, sometimes large). Without actual knowledge, you won't be able to spot and fix those mistakes, and it will come back to bite you in the ass.
Moving on...
Anonymous Apex is basically an "Inner Class" and not a "Top-Level Type"
Like the error says, you can't have static things appear in inner classes.
You'll need to create an actual Apex Class (through the dev console or some other means) to hold this test code. You'll also need to deploy this test class alongside the Apex class that holds the actual logic that you hope to run, at the same time. That's because the tests that get run are the tests that exist in your target org (and not from the sandbox you're developing this in)
Recommendation
You should go through the following modules on Trailhead to start to build some understanding. You don't need to know everything about Apex, but the more you know, the better (and the fewer roadblocks like this that you'll run into):

Apex Basics for Admins
Apex Basics and Database (which is a bit more programmer-focused, hence my recommendation to go through the "for admins" module first)
Apex Testing

